# Excel group row if value less than number specified

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

I have a sample data as following:

| Item | Qty |

| -------- | -------------- |

| A    | 18            |

| B   | 18            |

| C    | 7            |

| D   | 20            |

| E    | 13            |

| F   | 2            |

| G   | 3            |

| H   | 20            |

I would like to group the row so that if the qty is less than a specific number, lets say 25 (the number on column qty won't be bigger than 25), it will be placed on group 1. And then, if the row below it added to the current row is still less than 25, then it will be placed on the same group. otherwise it will be on the different group

Below is the value that I would like to achieve

| Item | Qty | Group |

| --- | --- | --- |

| A    | 18            | 1 |

| B   | 18            | 2 |

| C    | 7            | 2 |

| D   | 20            | 3 |

| E    | 13            | 4 |

| F   | 2            | 4 |

| G   | 3            | 4 |

| H   | 20            | 5 |

Hope my question didn't confused you.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I understand you want to group items together sequentially, in groups of no more than 25.

What you need is a running total column, which will tell you how much is in each group. This total will "reset" when you start a new group number.

Lets say col A is Item, B is Qty, C is Total, and D is Group number. Row 1 contains the headers and data starts in A2 and B2.

C2:

```
=B2
```

D2:

```
=1
```

C3:

```
=IF(C2+B3 <= 25, C2+B3, B3)
```

D3:

```
=IF(C2+B3 <= 25, D2, D2+1)
```

Now copy and paste the formulae in C3 and D3 down to your last row. Additionally hide column C if the total doesn't interest you.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do this without a helper column. Assuming data starts in row 2, in columns A-C.

You are trying to find out if the contents of the current box / batch / group plus the current row exceed the capacity of 25, in which case we start a new box / group.

Or to put it another way, does this row have more items than fit in the remaining space in the current box / group.

So we need to find out how many items are in the last box already, using a SUMIF, and carefully constructing it so it only counts rows above the current one, to avoid circular references. In C19 for example this would look like:

```
SUMIF($C$2:$C18,$C18,$B$2:$B18)
```

Translating, this is:
SUM all cells in column B above this one (from $B$2 down to $B18, note the lack of a dollar sign here so it will change on every row) but only where column C has the same value as the row above this one (the current group / box).
That tells us what is already in the current group.

You can either add the current quantity and check if the total is less than or equal to 25, or take it away first and then compare. If it fits, use the value from the cell above, otherwise add 1. You need to start with a "1" in cell C2, then in C3 use:

```
=IF($B3<=(25-SUMIF($C$2:$C2,$C2,$B$2:$B2)),$C2,$C2+1)
```

or

```
=IF($B3+SUMIF($C$2:$C2,$C2,$B$2:$B2))<=25,$C2,$C2+1)
```

Which are equivalent, but one might make more sense than the other in logical terms when you are troubleshooting.
Copy this all the way down column C as far as needed.